# timestamp to XML and then from XML, how?

Tags: sql, xml, timestamp

people! i need some help in this
I have a TABLE with timestamp field and i want to use WCF service to transfer data into other SQL Server
Now, I try to simulate this, using "for xml"

```
DECLARE @aa XML
DECLARE @idoc int
SET @aa =(select * from db_table for xml auto, elements, root('root'), type)
```

select @aa returns

```
<root>
<Person>
 <preson_id>1</preson_id>
 <Name>Иван</Name>
 <Surname>Иванов</Surname>
 <BurthDate>1915-05-03</BurthDate>
 <guid>2E739E87-3CA4-4ED8-ADD0-8B59957668B8</guid>
 <version>AAAAAAAAB9E=</version>
</Person>
<Person>
 <preson_id>2</preson_id>
 <Name>Николай</Name>
 <Surname>Николаев</Surname>
 <BurthDate>2005-03-05</BurthDate>
 <guid>BDC41C59-D70F-4B70-954E-4918B9516AF8</guid>
 <version>AAAAAAAAB9I=</version>
</Person>
<Person>
 <preson_id>3</preson_id>
 <Name>Максим</Name>
 <Surname>Максимов</Surname>
 <BurthDate>1845-11-15</BurthDate>
 <guid>740E57F3-56BA-48B8-92AF-978D7B1D2712</guid>
 <version>AAAAAAAAB9M=</version>
</Person>
</root>
```

It's look good for the first look, but when i try to take data from xml, timestamp values looks not good(

```
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @aa
SELECT * FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/root/Person',2)
   WITH db_table
```

How can i take from xml timestamp values in source look?

Sorry for my not good English)))

Comment: What implementation of SQL are you using?  SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle?

Comment: On a side note, your XML (and the DB it's created from) has spelling mistakes in its element names. BurthDate should be BirthDate and preson_id should be person_id

Comment: and what do the timestamp values you extract from the XML look like?  Where is the timestamp field? I can only see a date in BurthDate

Comment: Spelling mistakes in elements names don't critical. I noticed them.

Comment: I use SQL Server 2008 Enterprise, for example, in first row timestamp value is 0x00000000000007D1, xml looks like AAAAAAAAB9E=, and SELECT * FROM OPENXML returns 0x4100410041004100 in all rows)

Answer (score 0):

If you use MS SQL Server 2005 or later you can do this instead

```
select
    r.p.value('preson_id[1]', 'int') as preson_id,
    r.p.value('BurthDate[1]', 'date') as BurthDate,
    r.p.value('guid[1]', 'uniqueidentifier') as guid,
    r.p.value('version[1]', 'rowversion') as timestamp
from @aa.nodes('root/Person') r(p)
```

Comment: That's great, can you give me a link to reed more about nodes, and r.p.value construction?